# Passing a list and object as parameters

Tags: python, class, object, parameters

I'm translating a java code into python but java uses an array and python uses a list. I'm trying to pass a list as a parameter in Python that also needs to pass an object in the same parameter to addObject().

Declared List of Objects monsters=[ ] in SaveTheTribe.py

```
class SaveTheTribe():
    def __init__(self):
        self.map = Map()
        self.soldier = Soldier()
        self.spring = Spring()
        self.monsters = []
        self.gameEnabled = True

    def initialize(self):
        self.monsters.append(Monster(1, random.randint(0, 4)*10 + 30))
        self.monsters[0].setPos(4,1)
        self.monsters[0].addDropItem(2)
        self.monsters[0].addDropItem(3)

       ...

        self.monsters.append(Monster(7, random.randint(0, 4) * 10 + 30))
        self.monsters[6].setPos(4, 7)
        self.monsters[6].addDropItem(-1)
        self.monsters[6].addHint(6)

        self.map.addObject(self.monsters)

        self.soldier.setPos(1,1)
        self.soldier.addKey(1)
        self.soldier.addKey(5)

        self.map.addObject(self.soldier)

        self.spring.setPos(7,4)

        self.map.addObject(self.spring)
```

Need to pass monsters lists and soldier & spring objects

```
class Map():
    def __init__(self):
        self.cells = [[None]*7]*7
        for i in range(7):
            for j in range(7):
                self.cells[i][j] = Cell()
        self.occupiedObject = None

    def addObject(self, object):
        pos = Pos()

        if (isinstance(object, Monster)):
            print("is of monster instance")
            for monster in object:
                pos = monster.getPos()
                self.cells[pos.getRow()-1][pos.getColumn()-1].setOccupiedObject(monster)
        else:
            if isinstance(object, Soldier):
                print("is of soldier instance")
                pos = object.getPos()
            elif isinstance(object, Spring):
                print("is of spring instance")
                pos = object.getPos()

            if (pos !=None):
                self.cells[pos.getRow()-1][pos.getColumn()-1].setOccupiedObject(object)
```

Right now the monsters list does not satisfy the if condition in the addObjects() because I guess monsters is simply a reference to a list and not the object itself? How should I fix this?

Comment: Add another test `if isinstance(object, list):`

Comment: @Barmar That fixed the problem. You're a genius!

Comment: But having a method that needs to perform all those `isinstance()` checks violates good OO design. There should be a method that all the monster types implement, and `addObject()` should call it.